# Fields in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

```
class @A
   A_Function_Alias: => @my_function

   my_function: =>

   usage_of_alias: =>
      @A_Function_Alias.call()
```

What i want, is `usage_of_alias` to be

> usage_of_alias: =>
>           @A_Function_Alias

And have it behave the same. i.e. I want a more functional style syntax here. I've tried multiple combinations with no success. The fact that i have to evaluate my function to get the goodies inside bothers me.

One application would be instead of this:

```
event: => new Event(@my_function)
```

which is accessed as `event.call().hi()`

i could have some other declaration that would allow me to access event as `event.hi()`

Something that behaves more like a field instead of a property.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Rather, the why, if you could post some more code, maybe something more domain specific I'm sure we could help solve your problem. You shouldn't have to use `eval`, that's for sure.

Comment: Is `usage_of_alias: @A_Function_Alias` what you want?  Its not clear exactly what you're going for.

Comment: I just don't want to have to use the .call(). The meaning for doing this is purely cosmetic. It seems as if bound functions cannot point to other bound functions unless they are themselves bound functions.

Comment: I made some edits that may clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you want this:

```
class @A
   my_function: => alert 'my function!'

   A_Function_Alias: @::my_function

   usage_of_alias: =>
      @A_Function_Alias()
      # some other code...
```

*[See what this compiles to here.](https://gist.github.com/1928093)*

When evaluating a class `@` is the class constructor object, the class object itself.  And the `::` operator lets you drill into the prototype.  So `@::foo` in a class body compiles to `MyClass.prototype.foo`.

So what this is doing is first making a normal instance method named `my_function`, defined on `A.prototype.my_function`.  Then we make a new instance method named `A_Function_Alias` and directly assign the function from class objects prototype that we just created.  Now `my_function` and `A_Function_Alias` both point to the exact same function object.

---

But as a more sane alternative, might I suggest a pattern that defines a private inner function that the class can use, and then assigning it more directly, without crazy the prototype accessing?

```
class @A

  # Only code inside this class has access to this local function
  innerFunc = -> alert 'my function!'

  # Assign the inner funciton to any instance methods we want.
  my_function: innerFunc
  A_Function_Alias: innerFunc

  usage_of_alias: =>
    @A_Function_Alias()
    # or
    @my_function()
    # or
    innerFunc()
    # they all do the same thing
```

Comment: This looks really good, thanks. I understand your suggestion for an alternative. I need a namespace for events so that i can use jQuery 1.7's on and off api's. Since i don't have reflection in CoffeScript to use the method name as a namespace I'm creating a wrapper for my event. It looks like this:

`event: => new Event("Class.method", @method)`

I want to bind the event by just passing in event instead of event.call() to my View. I also don't want to inline my event creation so that it is easier to test without the use of an EventFactory or implementing Event.equals().

Comment: Ahh. there is a binding issue with this approach. I'll have more info soon i hope.

Comment: Ok, this is all because i was missing a require statement that put me through this whole ordeal.

Comment: My final solution was to assign the fields in my constructor. That removes the funky syntax.